# Replace a substring in a list of str only when the substring is alone - python

Tags: python, string, replace

Let us suppose I have a list of string:

```
l = ['firm incorp', 'firm2 inc']
```

and I only want to remove the suffix `'inc'` from the second entry but if I do the following

```
l_r = [s.replace('inc', '') for s in l]
```

I'll remove the substring `inc` from the first entry as well. What is the most effective way to handle this?
NB: the suffix I want to remove are, in principle, only at the end of the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the string only found at word boundaries using regular expression:

```
import re

l_r = [re.sub(r'\binc$', '', s) for s in l]
```

`\b` is special character matching word boundaries, `$` means the end of the string or just before the newline at the end of the string. For further information read the [re docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).

Comment: In the rare case that you have `inc inc` this will fail, but i doubt that would happen

Comment: @jamylak well it will produce a white space only string which, to my understanding, is the expected result

Comment: You could easily handle it by changing last `\b` to `$`

Comment: @jamylak I agree, I am simply not sure if that is what OP really wants

Comment: OP said suffix, meaning at the end so i think `$` is suitable

Comment: On the other hand Op does state **suffix**, will edit

Comment: yes in principle they are only suffix, and they are only at the end of my string.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution without regex:

```
l = ['firm incorp', 'firm2 inc']
l2 = [' '.join(j for j in i.split(' ') if j != 'inc') for i in l]

# ['firm incorp', 'firm2']
```

Comment: What if a guy's first name was `inc` and his firm was called `inc jackson & co` :P

Comment: @jamylak, in that case, your answer is preferable :)

Comment: This is a bit ridiculous but I just found a real life example: https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcompany&CIK=0001050067&owner=exclude&count=40&hidefilings=0

`INC RESEARCH INC` which this would remove both incs (if we converted to lowercase)

Comment: I tried, to down-vote my own post, but - alas - it's not possible!

Comment: If you edit your post I can change my upvote to a downvote if that would make you feel better. (I wouldnt do it if i were you)

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> items = ['firm incorp', 'firm2 inc']
>>> [s[:-4] if s.endswith(' inc') else s for s in items]
['firm incorp', 'firm2']
```